# How do I vertically center form view in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use a form for a username/password login screen
By default, the form aligns to the top of the screen, but I want it center aligned vertically and horizontally.
Any ideas on how to do that?

```
struct LoginView: View {

@State var username: String = ""

@State var password: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                
                TextField("Password", text: $password)
            }
    }
    .frame(width: 400, height: 200, alignment: .center)
    
}
}
```

[this is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWVs4.png)

I tried using a VStack and using a .frame modifier but I got a result that looked like this which is NOT what I want

[This is with .frame and VStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8xma.png)

Comment: Would you be able to post the code of the current view? This will help us help you! [Tips on Creating Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) On initial thought, you would need to place a Spacer() surrounding the items in the VStack - a spacer on both the top of and below the content.

Comment: Hey, I just updated the question with some code, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground)
                List {
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    TextField("Password", text: $password)
                }
            Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```